# Why two separate string join to one? By append, Python

Tags: python, sockets, select, append

I am trying to accept connections from two remote machines. They send me two strings. And then it will join these into one. Why?

My part of code:

```
readable, writable, exceptional = select.select(parents, [], [])
    for i in readable:
        text=i.recv(1024)
        text=text.decode('utf-8')
        updated.append(text)
```

and result is:

```
['string1string2']
```

but I need something like that:

```
['string1','string2']
```

Where is the problem? Why doesn't it work properly?

Comment: What does ```updated``` start as and how many times does the loop run?

Comment: updated = [], loop is neverending, select is waiting, and when something will come, it should be added to 'updated'

Comment: @wnnmaw: that's hardly the problem..

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I thought that if ```updated``` starts as ```[]```, and then ```text = "string1string2"``` when it is appended, that could lead to this result.  Probably not what's happening, just my first guess

Comment: @wnnmaw: Either `text`, as received, is `'string1string2'`, *or* nothing is received and `updated` started out with that value. The latter is unlikely.

Comment: I dont see any problem. can u tell the format of `readable`?

Comment: @Arvind: See [`select.select()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html#select.select); it's a list of sockets ready to read data from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data from the remote machine is received as a single byte stream. Even if the remote end does something like

```
print >>socket, "string1"
print >>socket, "string2"
```

on your end the data read by `recv` will be the string `string1\nstring2\n` (ignoring details like which end-of-line characters are actually sent and received). You have to take care of splitting the data yourself. From your question, it's not clear if there are *any* intervening characters between the end of the first string and the beginning of the second string, so there's no way (on your end) on determining what the split point should be.

There must be *some* protocol established which both you and the remote agree to for how to send and interpret a series of distinct words or lines of text.

Comment: Thank you, I used separator character, and then splited it.. It works :)